# How to stay energetic after work

Tags: sleep, energy

I am very energetic when it comes to work. But once I reach home why I feel so tired that I can't focus on anything except sleeping. What could keep me going and keep me energized after office?

Comment: Did you already perform some kind of self analysis? Are you tired because you are not sleeping rigth and don´t get enough rest? Is it the work which is to hard? to stressful? to unfulfilling?  Are you also tired on weekends? Did you visit a doctor for a blood analysis? Is your diet healthy? There are so many factors... Sorry, but best look for professional help and don´t ask the internet about potential medical problems :)

Comment: @Julian you gave me very good analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Bring your gym kit with you to work. Don't allow yourself to go home before your go to the gym.